# SVN remote server and Excel on local

Tags: svn, excel

I have a remote SVN server, where I keep my files (for web devel). I'm using a tool, that can directly pull files from SVN repository, and check them in/out, so I have no other SVN tool on my local computer. I'm using the svn:// path style.

Now, I realised I need to store an Excel file I'm working on locally, in that remote SVN as well. What is the way how to achieve this ? Do I need to install something like TortoiseSVN on my local computer as well, or is there any tool or plugin, that allows me to save directly from Excel to (remote) SVN ? Ideally, I need to commit every "save" from Excel to SVN as new version, but I guess thats not possible.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few weeks, I'm back to answer my own question so others may use it :)

1. I needed to install TortoiseSVN on my local computer.
2. I downloaded and installed the MSOfficeSVN plugin from 
   http://code.google.com/p/msofficesvn/
3. A new bar appeared in Office (Word, Excel) programs, allowing me to check in/out documents directly to/from remote server, exactly as needed.

Piece of cake :)

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is probably your best route. I don't know of any tool or plugin that allows you to check-in your workbook directly from Excel. I think you'll need to check each revision in manually from Windows Explorer using Tortoise.

This isn't such a bad thing really - checking in your workbook with every save means that you'd lose some of the power of the Source Control Manager. For example, what if you wanted to make some experimental changes, then find they didn't work? If you haven't committed the changes, you can just revert to the latest revision in Subversion.